# scrollTop only working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

The script works fine in Firefox, but in other browsers the jump to functions does not work. It only highlights the found term. Please help!

```
function highlightTerms()
{
   var searchTerm = $('#search-term').val();
     $("p:contains('"+searchTerm+"')").addClass('highlighted');
}

function unhighlight()
{
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
}

function scrollToFirstFoundTerm()
{
   var firstFoundTerm = $('.highlighted:first');
   if (firstFoundTerm.length > 0)
      $('html').scrollTop(firstFoundTerm.offset().top);
}

function searchAndHighlight()
{
   unhighlight();
   highlightTerms();
   scrollToFirstFoundTerm();

}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: In future questions, please add a descriptive title of the specific problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop(firstFoundTerm.offset().top);
```

Should work cross browser with the addition of `body`.